# Nexus 5 suddenly not recognized by Eclipse on Windows

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I was debugging an Android App when suddenly the Eclipse ADT I am using stopped recognizing my Nexus5. 
The smartphons has the developer options turned on, usb debugging enabled, it is not listed in the adb devices.

What is happening? How may i fix it?

UPDATE

If i try adb kill-server and then plug the device Windows recognize it is a Nexus 5 But Eclipse can't connect to it. Then I try to start the serve with adb start-server but Eclipse says no device is plugged

Answer (score 0):

Try revoking the permissions on the device - Developer options -> Revoke USB debugging authorizations. Then plug the device in and accept it again.

if that doesnt work then:

set your ANDROID_SDK_HOME again and:

- unplug device
- adb kill-server
- adb start-server
- plug device

Comment: consider that Windows itself doesn't recognize the phone when plugged

Comment: Change the USB MODE to media

Answer (score 0):

- Since you mentioned windows, Open task manager, and kill all adb.exe processes.
- Restart Eclipse
- Disconnect and Connect your Nexus 5